# Automating some commands in shell

Tags: shell

Say i need to run a couple of commands automatically in a shell everytime i open the shell. how can i automate that?

For Example:

I need to automate the following:

1. open a shell
2. cd /specific folder
3. find . -name 'app_logs'

Answer (score 1):

If it's BASH then you can put these commands into ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 1):

It depends what OS and Terminal you're using. I imagine most of the popular terminal allows you to customise the startup command. For example, in the Terminal.app that comes with Mac OS X, you can go to Preferences > Settings > Shell > Startup / run command to specify a script to run on startup of each terminal window/tab.

Or you can simply at the commands at `$HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc`, depending on your OS and shell.